# Use of .data() method to pass a switch into a function

Tags: jquery, function

I have a modal dialogue invoked when div.artLink is clicked (see below).  However, I want to suppress the modal dialogue when the visitor clicks on an anchor element.

I've tried using the .data() method to pass the fact of an anchor being clicked to my modal function but without success.
My knowledge of jQuery is limited so I apologise if this seems a naive question...

Can anybody nudge me in the right direction?

```
<div class="artLink">
    <img src="/assets/press/article03_thumb.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="article">
        <img src="/assets/press/article03_main.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <ul class="paLinks">
        <li>MODAL DIALOGUE</li>
        <li><a href="<url>" >EXTERNAL LINK</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

script be

```
// Detect if an anchor has been clicked...
$('ul.paLinks a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});

// Load modal dialog on click
$('.artLink').click(function () {                             

    // Only activate modal dialogue if an anchor has NOT been clicked...
    if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {
        $('.article',this).modal(... );
    }
});
```

Comment: You're attaching the data to the anchor element itself, but then you check for the `data` object of the parent `artLink` element.

Comment: event bubbling is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simpler check. Just make sure that `e.target.nodeName !== 'A'`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/6Wz3m/)

```
$('.artLink').click(function(e){

   if(e.target.nodeName !== 'A') {// or use jQuery.fn.is for complex criteria
        console.log(this); //invoke modal logic here
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Yury - that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.stopPropagation()`. it prevent event bubbling from the dom tree and use `event.preventDefault()` it stops the default action of href in a tag

```
// Detect if an anchor has been clicked...
$('ul.paLinks a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
});

// Load modal dialog on click
$('.artLink').click(function () {                             

    // Only activate modal dialogue if an anchor has NOT been clicked...
    if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {
        $('.article',this).modal(... );
    }
});
```

Comment: But why `event.preventFefault();`?

Comment: The OP doesn't want to disable the anchor element's behavior.